# How to debug a crash that occur even if there is breakpoint at line 1?

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

I'm working on a program but this program crashes no matter where I put a breakpoint ( even when it's before the first instruction in `main()` ). I use the very basic code::blocks.

Do you know a method to debug it?

If I set no breakpoint, `main()` is fully executed before crashing ( there is one thing that does not give the expected results though ).

Comment: If you run your program under a debugger, doesn't it break at the "crash"? You could then inspect the program state and see what lead to the crash.

Comment: Ah. True. Woops. Why didn't I think about it :o Thanks. It's a seg fault btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All debuggers that I know of break in the case of a segfault and allow you to inspect the current program state and see what lead to the crash.

So in a way, outright segfaults can be pretty easy to debug since you don't have to figure out where to place the breakpoint :-)

Comment: I know where is the problem now, thank you =) A destructor cause a segfault (i try to destroy an object containing vector of the same object, looks like i'm doing it not as i should)

Comment: Just wrote an answer so you had something to accept *hint* *hint* :-)